# Why is std::byte an enum class instead of a class?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, language-design, std-byte

`std::byte` is an abstraction that is supposed to provide a type safe(r) access to regions of memory in C++, starting with the new standard 17. However, it's declared this way according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte:

```
enum class byte : unsigned char {} ;
```

That is, it is an `enum class`  without any enumerations. Since usually the purpose of `enums` is to provide a restricted set of enumerations, this seems a bit strange. A class with a private `unsigned char` member seems like the more obvious way to do this.

Why is it done this way?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A `class` with an `unsigned char` member would not be required by the standard to be the same size or alignment as `unsigned char`. Whereas the standard requires that enumerations be the same size and alignment as their underlying types.

Now, the standard could have simply declared that it is a `class` type with no standard-defined member, but with specific requirements on its size, alignment, `constexpr` constructors, etc; implementations would have to follow through on those expectations. But it's much easier to simply use `enum class` to get the same effect. You get all of the constructors and conversion behavior that you'd expect. And since `enum class` types are treated as different types than their underlying type, you get all of the behavior you want with no real downside to defining it this way.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by the accepted answer, the goal is for `std::byte` to have the same size, alignment, and representation as `unsigned char`. Implementations have too much freedom when it comes to classes. For example, implementations are not prevented from over-aligning `struct byte { unsigned char b; };`, although none over-align in practice.

You can find more rationale in the proposal for `std::byte`, [P0298 - A byte type definition](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0298r3.pdf):

> #### Implementation Alternatives
>
> Two possible definitions of `std::byte` were originally considered:
>
> ```cpp
> // Alternative A:
> namespace std {
>     enum class byte : unsigned char {};
> }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```cpp
> // Alternatve B:
> namespace std {
>     using byte = /* implementation defined */;
> }
> ```
>
> We find alternative A easier to present and explain to ordinary programmers. For all practical purposes,
> it has the right semantics. After presenting both alternatives to the Library Working Group, straw polling
> showed unanimous support for the Alternative A, which is the form presented in this paper.