# std::is_enum_v<std::byte> evaluates to true

Tags: c++, enums, type-traits, std-byte

According to the [standard reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum), `std::is_enum_v` evaluates to true for enumeration types and to false otherwise. An [enumeration type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) starts with an enum key, i.e. either one of enum, enum class or enum struct.

In wrote the following testprogram:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using to_examine = std::byte;

enum class Foo {
    ONE,
    TWO 
};

int main() {
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<std::byte>) {
        std::cout << "byte counts as enum" << std::endl;
    }   

    if constexpr(std::is_enum_v<int>) {
        std::cout << "int counts as enum" << std::endl;
    }   

    if constexpr(std::is_enum_v<Foo>) {
        std::cout << "scoped enum counts as enum" << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

which prints out the following:

```
byte counts as enum
scoped enum counts as enum
```

I am working with clang15 and g++12. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: `std::byte` is defined by the standard to be an [enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508172/why-is-stdbyte-an-enum-class-instead-of-a-class

Comment: Ah, another fun part of this language...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::byte` is defined by the standard as an enumeration type.

See [`std::byte` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte):

> ```cpp
> enum class byte : unsigned char {};   // (since C++17)
> ```

If you are interested in the reason it is defined like this, there's some info here:

- [P02983 - A byte type definition](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0298r3.pdf) (the proposal which added `std::byte` to the standard)
- [Why is `std::byte` an enum class instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508172/why-is-stdbyte-an-enum-class-instead-of-a-class.)